# wifi is not working, audio is not playing

Tags: wifi-direct

i inistalled the ubuntu yesterday in to my computer, this is not my computer, my computer's model is dell latitude d630

audio is not working, also my wifi is not working.

if i try to install any software, it can'nt install, i don't now what to do, \

i have not wired internet connection , it only wifi connection

so please help me, if you help me please call my my tell is this 252907720851, or send me sms to telling me you sent me email or any thing that you can help me, so please

help me,

Answer (score 2):

Before you start up, you need Wired Internet connection.

For your Wi-Fi/Wireless:

For your wireless:

- Connect your computer with Wired Internet Connection.
- Open the 'System Settings' from your launcher bar.
- Select 'Software & Updates' for the System Settings Window.
- Now, select the 'Additional Drivers' tab.
- Now, select the option 'Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)'.
- Click on 'Apply Changes'. Now your wireless will start working.

And before installing any packages or drivers, please update or upgrade your system,

- Open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)
- Type the below command

  `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

And as for your Audio or Video, the easiest way is to install Vlc Media Player, to do so,

- Open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)
- Type the below command

  `sudo apt-get install vlc`

I hope it'd work for you.